# auditd taking 199% CPU on CentOS7.6

Tags: centos, webserver, linux-audit

I have a small VPS server running CentOS 7.6. Auditd repeatedly takes 199% CPU, basically rendering the system unusable. If I `kill` it, things calm down for a few days and then the problem returns. I've already restarted the machine, for no avail.

Ideas? Thanks

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to disable audited or make it work but take less than 199% of the CPU or something else?

Comment: I need it to work, but not take the machine down. I assume up to 5% makes sense. 10% tops.

Comment: Have you changed anything in the auditd configuration? As the https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/auditing-the-system_security-hardening warns you, system performance may be affected by running auditd. Is it possible that recording audit events is creating fresh audit events leading to the total CPU usage you are seeing?

Comment: What is the output of `auditctl -l`, and that's the purpose of this web server?

Comment: $ sudo auditctl -l
No Rules

This is a web server, running Playframework on Scala (so, a JVM) and Postgresql.

Comment: Re: changes in the config files, I've only increased the frequency, as I've seen at some forums that it may help (in this case it didn't)

Comment: mdatp (microsoft defender) may cause this if you have it installed. (systemctl status mdatp)